# One script changing multiple UI images, but it's not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm having trouble with this code I'm trying to make.

**My goal:** Make each level button have that level's rank on it as well,
but I'm trying to do it from one script.

Firstly, here's how I have set up everything:

[image]

Those are the ranks inside each button and with a **Rankdictator** script that I made inside each rank gameobject.

Here's the script for the **Rankdictator**:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Rankdictator : MonoBehaviour
{
    int levelnumberrank;
    private Image thisimage;
    public Sprite rankgold;
    public Sprite ranksilver;
    public Sprite rankbronze;
    public Sprite blank;
    private Levellockcheck levellockcheck;

    public void Start()
    {

        levellockcheck = FindObjectOfType<Levellockcheck>();
        thisimage = this.GetComponent<Image>();
        levelnumberrank = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(("rankoflevel") + (levellockcheck.thisbuttonlevel));
        if(levelnumberrank == 3)
        {
            thisimage.sprite = rankgold;
        }
        else if(levelnumberrank == 2)
        {
            thisimage.sprite = ranksilver;
        }
        else if (levelnumberrank == 1)
        {
            thisimage.sprite = rankbronze;
        }
        else if (levelnumberrank == 0)
        {
            thisimage.sprite = blank;
        }
    }
}
```

Now here's the problem. **As I said, the ranks don't show on each button correctly when there are multiple buttons active**, however, **when I only have one button active, the rank shows**. Here's an example:

[image]

That is when I have both buttons active. (Level 1 should have full rank and level 2 should have low rank. But it's showing nothing)

Now here's when only one button is active. It shows correctly.

[image]

### Edit

I already used Debug.Log to confirm the levelnumberrank on each button and it references as expected.

But, it still doesn't reference the rank on each button when all of them are active, only does so when one button is active while the others are inactive.

Comment: Put in `Debug.Log` statements to see what `levelnumberrank`, and `levellockcheck.thisbuttonlevel` are.  And make sure that you have the correct value in `PlayerPrefs`.

Comment: @BenRubin I did that already. Debug.Log gave the expected numbers. And like I said, when the button is by itself, it shows correctly. Everything is referencing correctly. The problem is that it won't reference on multiple buttons.

Comment: Put debug statements inside of each `if` block and see which ones are executing when you have one button and which ones are executing when you have multiple buttons.

Comment: @BenRubin I'll try that. Will update in a bit

Comment: @BenRubin OK. I did what you said. The results were confusing. Turns out that it takes the levelnumberrank of the last button. So, if all four are active, it would take the fourth level rank. If three are active, it would take the third, etc

Comment: @BenRubin basically it doesn't assign the rank of each level to its own button, it assigns the rank of the last button to all the buttons.

Comment: @BenRubin I figured it out. Check my answer!

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

I figured the problem out: it was the levellockcheck!

On each button, there was a levellockcheck script with a public int thisbuttonlevel.

I was, on each Rankdictator, referencing the levellockcheck like so:

```
Levellockcheck = FindObjectofType<levellockcheck>();

levelnumberrank = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(("rankoflevel") + (levellockcheck.thisbuttonlevel));
```

By doing that, I'm referencing different numbers all at the same time from each single button. Because the (thisbuttonlevel) on each button was different.

What I was supposed to do on Rankdictator:

```
Levellockcheck = this.GetComponentInParent<levellockcheck>();
```

By doing that, I referenced the (thisbuttonlevel) of the button itself.

And now:

[image]

It works!